# Converting inputs into lists

Tags: python

```
number = input("Enter numbers separated by spaces: ")
if int(number)>5:
    print ('Invalid  Input')
elif int(number)<0:
        print ('Invalid  Input')
elif len(number) !=5 :
        print ('Invalid  Input')
elif len(number) == 5:
    for n in number:
        a = int(n)
        if 0< a <=5:
            print ('x'* a)
        elif a == 0:
            print ('.')
```

The problem is the code treats the 5 digits as one number.  The program is supposed to check if the 5 inputted numbers meet all the conditions and if even one them does not, the program should print INVALID INPUT and the program should then stop.  I want the program to check if the conditions are met before doing anything, if they are not for even one digit the program should print invalid input and nothing else.  How can I convert the inputted number into a list and then check if each element of the list meets the conditions?

-The program should check the inputted number  before printing anything
-The program must check that the input are numbers are between 0 and 5.  It will also fail if a number of digits is entered other than 5.  Failed input can terminate the program with an appropriate error message.
-Inputted numbers may be duplicates. (ex. 3, 3, 3, 0, 0 is acceptable input.)

Comment: How have you tried to solve this problem? What resources did you look at?

Comment: Might I suggest changing the prompt to "Enter 5 numbers separated by spaces: "?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the input so that you have each number separated. You're trying to turn a string of '3 0 3 3 0' into an integer, which isn't possible.

```
In [1]: userInput = input().split()
3 0 3 3 0 # the input I gave

In [2]: userInput
Out[2]: ['3', '0', '3', '3', '0']
```

From there, you can convert each number to an integer and do the value checking that you want to do, which isn't possible on the list of strings. You can do the first part of that easily with a list comprehension:

```
numbers = [int(number) for number in userInput]
```